# Program Output Differs Dramatically Under Valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I have an executable I'm running on a remote linux machine.

When I run the executable normally (./execute arg_one), the program crashes in the middle of a while loop " Error in `./execute': malloc(): memory corruption (fast)"

However, when I run the program under the simplest valgrind (valgrind ./execute arg_one), the program doesn't crash, runs all the way through main, and actually produces the correct output.

Why would this be the case??

Comment: I don't know but you could try `MALLOC_CHECK_=2 ./execute arg_one`, too.

Comment: How do you run valgrind? It could produce the "*correct*" output, that's why it's called UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR.

Comment: Use `valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./execute arg_one` and check the errors there. Your program must be doing something that will piss off valgrind.

Comment: so iharob, you're saying it's not unusual for valgrind to ignore certain types of issues and cause a program to run differently? my perception was, it was meant to mimic the normal program fully

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens that your program crashes, but as valgrind is executing it very slowly it is possible that valgrind runs it to the end, and with the correct output. But it doesn't mean that your program is correct. You should check the errors/contexts shown by valgrind and correct them if you want your program to work.